# Statistic ARMA model

Tags: statistics, time-series

$Xt = 5+0.8(X_{t−1} −5)+0.8(X_{t−2} −5)−0.6(X_{t−3} −5)−0.5e_{t−1} + 0.25e_{t−2} +e_t$

Write the process using characteristic equations then determine ARIMA order and E[Xt]. Finally, find the values for E [▽Xt] and determine if ▽Xt is stationary and invertible. Actually, I am confused how to find E[Xt].

Comment: what is meant by  ▽Xt

Comment: ▽Xt= $X_t - X_{t−1}$

Comment: I provides an answer to your question below.

Comment: if the answer gives the solution to your questions and is helpful, please accept and vote it.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you may expand the equation as follows
\begin{aligned}
X_t = 5 + 0.8 X_{t-1}- 4 + 0.8 X_{t-2} - 4 - 0.6 X_{t-3} + 3 + e_t - 0.5 e_{t-1} + 0.25 e_{t-2}
\end{aligned}
which is the same as
\begin{aligned}
X_t - 0.8 X_{t-1} - 0.8 X_{t-2} + 0.6 X_{t-3} = e_t - 0.5 e_{t-1} + 0.25 e_{t-2}
\end{aligned}
Using the backward shift operator $q^{-1}$ (defined by $q^{-k} X_t = X_{t-k}$ for every $t$ and positive $k$), it follows that
\begin{aligned}
(1 - 0.8 q^{-1}- 0.8 q^{-2} + 0.6 q^{-3}) X_t = (1 - 0.5 q^{-1} + 0.25 q^{-2})e_t
\end{aligned}

This gives that
\begin{aligned}
X_t = \frac{(1 - 0.5 q^{-1} + 0.25 q^{-2})}{(1 - 0.8 q^{-1}- 0.8 q^{-2} + 0.6 q^{-3}) }e_t
\end{aligned}
assuming that the division by $(1 - 0.8 q^{-1}- 0.8 q^{-1} + 0.6 q^{-1}) $ is valid.

Now you can compute the expectation. For example, $E[X_t] = 0$  for all $t$ if the errors $e_t$ have zero mean for all $t$.

The stationary of $X_t$ depends on the stationary of $e_t$ and the stability of the model. You need to check the roots of the characteristic polynomial (the denominator) and check the location of the roots with respect to the unit circle. It is easy to see that $X_t$ has a unit root and therefore it is not stationary.

From the second equation above one can see that (by multiplying both sides by the backward shift operator)
\begin{aligned}
X_{t-1} - 0.8 X_{t-2} - 0.8 X_{t-3} + 0.6 X_{t-4} = e_{t-1} - 0.5 e_{t-2} + 0.25 e_{t-3}
\end{aligned}

This means that
\begin{aligned}
(X_t - X_{t-1})   &- 0.8 (X_{t-1} - X_{t-2}) - 0.8 (X_{t-2}-X_{t-3}) + 0.6 (X_{t-3} - X_{t-4}) \\
&= e_t - 1.5 e_{t-1} + 0.75 e_{t-2} -0.25 e_{t-3}
\end{aligned}
which is the same as
\begin{aligned}
\nabla X_t   &- 0.8 \nabla X_{t-1} - 0.8 \nabla X_{t-2} + 0.6 \nabla X_{t-3}
= e_t - 1.5 e_{t-1} + 0.75 e_{t-2} -0.25 e_{t-3}
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\nabla X_t   =\frac{(1 - 1.5 q^{-1} + 0.75 q^{-2} - 0.25q^{-3})}{(1 - 0.8 q^{-1}- 0.8 q^{-2} + 0.6 q^{-3}) }e_t
\end{aligned}

Therefore, $E[\nabla X_t] = 0$ for all $t$ if $E[e_t] = 0$ for all $t$, and stationary is checked  again by checking the roots of the polynomial 
$$
1 - 0.8 q^{-1}- 0.8 q^{-2} + 0.6 q^{-3}
$$
in a similar manner as for $X_t$ above. It is easy to see that $\nabla X_t$ has a unit root and therefore it is not stationary. But because the roots of the numerator are strictly inside the unit circle, the process is invertible.

Comment: The commonly accepted notation for backshift operator is $B$ or $L$, where $B^kY_t = Y_{t-k}$. Also, is the expectation here for a non-stationary process $X_t$ given zero mean noise actually $0$?

Comment: Regarding notation, while $B$ and $L$ are used in the time series analysis literature, $q$ and $q^-1$ are used in engineering. Use the notations that you find convenient. Regarding the expectation, observe that it depends on the marginal distribution and due to its linearity and the stationarity assumption on $e$ it is equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what do you mean by "depends on the marginal distribution". All I know is that the expectation of an, say, AR(1) process $Y_t = a + b*Y_{t-1} + u$, where $u$ is a white noise, is equal to $\frac{a}{1 - b}$, right? And only if the $|b| < 1$. What happens with expectation if $|b| \ge 1$?

Comment: Isn't this formula only valid for stationary AR(1)? This is easy to see by noting that you compute it using E[y_t] =E[y_{t-1}]. Now notice what happens if a=0 and |b|>1 or |b|=1.

Comment: Ok so i guess for a = 0 it will always be 0 then? What if a is not 0? Thank you for your clarifications, by the way.

Comment: If $a$ is not zero, and $|b| \geq1$, the process is not stationary and it does not have a stationary distribution. In this case, if $|b|>1$ the mean will blow up and goes to infinity as time approach infinity. But for finite $t$ if you know the initial condition, for example assuming the process starts at $t = 0$ with initials equal to zero, you can still compute the mean by recursing the expression $E[Y_t] - b E[Y_{t-1}] = a$. For example, $E[Y_1] = a$, and $E[Y_2] = a + ab$, .. etc